# Jtree height of node with children

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a problem which I encountered when using `JTree` from Java Swing.

To be precise and exact I need to know the height of the node with its children (rows aren't the same in height). Is there any easy way to get that information?

EDIT:
Some nodes are visible, while others are not.

Comment: use this methods to compute the height of a given node: `public Rectangle getPathBounds(TreePath path)`. There are several methods to get the TreePath: getPathForRow, getSelectionPath... depending of what you have.

Comment: You need a recursive method which uses `public Rectangle getPathBounds(TreePath path)` to determine row height, and `public boolean isExpanded(TreePath path)` to determine whether the node is expanded or not (if not - you should stop the height calculation).

Comment: Ok so as i thought there is no easy way out of that problem and i have to create my own recursive method, thanks guys.